# How to do something with focused item of RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a simple RecyclerView with only a TextView as each item. By using `recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(myPosition);` in MainActivity, I can scroll to custom item. What I need is changing textColor for current item that is scrolled to, just after scrolling.

For example, if myPosition is 3 and 3rd item of RecyclerView is "current" or "focused", I want to change textColor for this 3rd item.

How can I do that?

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyAdapter.ItemClickListener {

    MyAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        ArrayList<String> itemTitle_List = new ArrayList<>();
        itemTitle_List.add("facebook");
        itemTitle_List.add("flickr");
        itemTitle_List.add("google_plus");
        itemTitle_List.add("instagram");
        itemTitle_List.add("linkedin");
        itemTitle_List.add("pinterest");
        itemTitle_List.add("soundcloud");
        itemTitle_List.add("swarm");
        itemTitle_List.add("tumblr");
        itemTitle_List.add("twitter");

        // set up the RecyclerView
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        adapter = new MyAdapter(this, itemTitle_List);
        adapter.setClickListener(this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(3);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
        //Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked " + adapter.getItem(position) + " on row number " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**MyAdapter.java:**

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<String> itemTitle_List;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;

    // data is passed into the constructor
    MyAdapter(Context context, List<String> itemTitle_List) {
        this.layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.itemTitle_List = itemTitle_List;
    }

    // inflates the row layout from xml when needed
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_row, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }


    // total number of rows
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return itemTitle_List.size();
    }


    // binds the title to the TextView, and image to the ImageView in each row
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        String title = itemTitle_List.get(position);
        holder.textView.setText(title);
    }



    // stores and recycles views as they are scrolled off screen
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        TextView textView;

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (itemClickListener != null) itemClickListener.onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }

    // convenience method for getting data at click position
    String getItem(int id) {
        return itemTitle_List.get(id);
    }

    // allows clicks events to be caught
    void setClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    // parent activity will implement this method to respond to click events
    public interface ItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**recyclerview_row.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: In recycler adapter use the textview to set it??

Comment: after click on 3th item or without click

Comment: Without clicking on 3rd item. just want to use recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(myPosition) for scroll to 3rd item, and then change textColor for it.

Comment: then get the position add the color to the textview..

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Extending `RecyclerView.SmoothScroller`and overriding the `onStop` method might be what you're looking for. You could create a callback interface between your `RecyclerView.SmoothScroller` and your adapter, and in your smooth scroller `onStop` method, calling something like `smoothScrollListener.didFinishSmoothScrolling`, which would update the text view of the item at the position you scrolled to.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm really beginner and I think can not do that.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution, but I'm not sure if this is standard or not.

Add a public integer, named **row_index=0** and a public function, in *MyAdapter.java*, as below:

```
public void selectRow(int index){
    row_index=index;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

And in the *onBindViewHolder* function in *MyAdapter.java*, add this code:

```
if(position==row_index){
    holder.textView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
}
else{
    holder.textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
}
```

Then, after `recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(3)` in *MainActivity.java*, use this:

```
MyAdapter.selectRow(3);
MyAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

This way, when RecyclerView scrolled to 3rd item, the textColor for this item changes to Red.